# Python 2.6 & IMAPLIB - Find folder or an email

Tags: python, imap

Is there a way to easily find which folder an email is in with the ID?  I have a method that loops through all the folders searching for it and exiting when it finds it, but there has to be a better way to just do one search and find the folder.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does [**`IMAP4.search`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.search) do what you want?

Comment: No, there isn't, unless you remembered where you downloaded it from.

Comment: No, you have to do an IMAP4.select on a folder first. (I believe)